# Photo gallery (slidshow) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, photo-gallery

Say there are several images that should be shown in the same box one by one. And images should change one after another by animation: current image opacity gradually becomes smaller while  next image becomes more opaque and, finally, first one disappears and next one appears.
Also this should be in a cycle and automatically, say one image per second. What do you suggest to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use this one for stuff like that http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: I like it, thanks :)! Is it possible to mark with bullets which slide is being shown? (For example I have three images, and it is being shown the second one, the I need to see three bullets on the slide - 1 and 3 white, 2 bullet black.)

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry to not be able to answer your second detailed question.